# Prove that there exists no solution for $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=c$

Tags: number-theory

If $a, b$ are non-square whole numbers, and $c$ is an positive whole number, prove there exists no solution to the following equation:

$$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=c$$

I have absolutely no idea where to start with this question as the possibilities of $a,b,c$ is too broad for what I am used to.

Comment: Over a thousand rep points and you don't even abide by the guidelines for asking a question?? What have you tried?

Comment: @jameselmore Sorry, bad habit of mine

Comment: Hint: could you answer this question if you knew that $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ was rational? If so, how could you show this?

Comment: $(\sqrt a)^2 = (c-\sqrt b)^2$. Now equate the coefficients of $\sqrt b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a solution exists. Then

$$\sqrt a = c-\sqrt b$$
$$a = c^2 + b -2\sqrt{b}$$
$$\sqrt b = \frac{c^2+b-a}2$$
$$b=\left(\frac{c^2+b-a}2\right)^2$$

Which shows that either b is the square of some non-integer (if $c^2+b-a$ is odd), i.e. b is not an integer, or that b is the square of an integer (if $c^2+b-a$ is even). Both cases lead to contradictions. Hence, there is no solution.